# Good database design - where to store a timestamp

Tags: database, timestamp

I'm wanting to know where is the best or most efficient way to store a time stamp in a database?

I was thinking that maybe I could create it's own table for it - but that seems somewhat inefficient to give it its own call.

Basically, the entire database only needs the one time stamp right now (though that might need to be expanded later on) to tell whether it is parsing data it already has or not.

How is the best (most efficient, not trying to be vague, if this is a point of contention)

Basically, if you need to store one, and only one date, how is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table with one column and only one row.  That's quite normal, but make sure that such tables will not start appearing in your database like dandelions.

Be very careful with your scheme "to tell whether it is parsing data it already has or not".  It might be better to use some IDs for the data that are not dependent on whether all database clients or other producers of the data have synchronized clocks, whether that time is never adjusted backward, whether the same data exists in multiple incompatible revisions, which timezones all components are running in, and what is the resolution and accuracy of any clocks involved.